# Vue2 Leaflet map gets overlapped by bottom navigation and app bar

Tags: vue.js, leaflet, vuetify.js

I would like to implement Vue2 Leaflet in my app but the problem is, it gets overlapped by `v-bottom-navigation` and `v-app-bar`. I was thinking maybe the leaflet's height is too big?

My code is wrapped in `v-content` and the app bar and bottom navigation bar have `app` property set to true.

Here's some very simple implementation:

```
<v-app>
   <v-app-bar app></v-app-bar>
   <v-content>
    <l-map>
    </l-map>
   </v-content>
   <v-bottom-navigation app></v-bottom-navigation>
</v-app>
```

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

As you can see the leaflet is being covered by the app bar and bottom nav bar. Could this be a vue2-leaflet issue?

Comment: Could you check the `z-index` values on the elements?

Comment: It's not about the `z-index`, if I'd set them to a higher level the map would simply overlap the bottom nav bar and the app bar instead of vice versa.

Comment: it looks like you're using vuetify. Check my repo if you want : https://github.com/fchabouis/parc-epique as I'm displaying a leaflet map in a vuetify app. The website : https://parc-epique.fr/#/

Comment: Thank you I'm going to give it a try.

Comment: @Istopopoki which version of Vuetify did you use to make your website? I made a very simple implementation of your map with 2 divs and like you did, the outer div has a height of 100% and the inner div has a width and height set to 100% so I have an empty map but it still gets overlapped by my bottom navigation and my app-bar.

Comment: an old version, I see in the package.json that it was vuetify 1.2.6

Comment: I tried cloning and running your project and it worked perfectly. As soon as I updated your Vuetify version to the latest, I encountered the same problem so if you plan on updating your packages I advise against it.

Comment: @Istopopoki I found the problem. I tried all previous Vuetify versions and I discovered that from Vuetify 2.0.0 beta.6 the .application component has been renamed to .v-application and your css styles would not apply because you used .application which does not work anymore.

Comment: cool @AndorNémeth, and it's working if you change the css selector ?

Comment: @Istopopoki yes, it's working then!

Comment: And thank you very much for your git repo, I could never have fixed this bug without it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone ever encounters the same problem in the future, here's the code that solved the problem for me after almost 2 weeks of painful bug searching:

```html
html,
body,
#app {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.v-application--wrap {
  min-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Copy this css code in your App.vue

If my answer is not clear enough, feel free to comment on it and I will try my best to help you!